# CMAKE set rc compiler flags?

Tags: cmake

CMake Version 3.4.3

Visual Studio 14 2015 Solution file

I am trying to set the location flag for rc compiler for CMAKE by using the following syntax however it is always set to the value /l"0x0409".

```
set(rc_flags "/l 0x809")
set(CMAKE_RC_FLAGS ${rc_flags})
```

Also CMAKE always sets flags for cl compiler for rc compiler which I cannot stop.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**

I have added version of cmake and visual studio version, the command still uses the /l"0x0409" flag when using the snippet from @Florian plus it uses flags I have specified for cl.exe command for rc.exe command which is not right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotation problem was fixed with CMake version 3.1 (see ["0010194: setting CMAKE_RC_FLAGS has no affect on rc flags"](https://cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=10194)).

So I've given your example a try with CMake version 3.6.0 and the "Visual Studio 14 2015" generator and the following code:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(TestRCCompilerFlags)

file(WRITE main.cpp "int main() { return 0; }")
file(WRITE main.rc "")

set(rc_flags "/l 0x809")
set(CMAKE_RC_FLAGS ${rc_flags})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp main.rc)
```

And - as expected - the `/l 0x809` option shows up under "Project Configuration Properties/Resources/Command Line/Additional Options". So I couldn't reproduce any quotation or ignored options problems.

[image]

**Makefile vs. Solution**

Generally speaking the RC command line - including its flags - is defined in [`CMakeRCInformation.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeRCInformation.cmake). But you only have the absolute control over the RC command line if using makefile generators. There you could overwrite `CMAKE_RC_COMPILE_OBJECT` variable in your `CMakeLists.txt` file to something like:

```
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_RC_COMPILER> /l 0x809 /fo<OBJECT> <SOURCE>")
```

The RC behavior of Visual Studio Solution generators is directly coded into [`cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator::WriteRCOptions()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator.cxx#L1866). This code doesn't (over-)write any RC `<Culture>` section, so there you will always see the default `/l"0x0409"` there. But the `<AdditionalOptions>` section generated by CMake will take care of this/overwrite those defaults.

Comment: Thanks Florian however using set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_RC_COMPILER> /l 0x809 /fo<OBJECT> <SOURCE>") doesn't work either.

Comment: @simon-p-r Some more information please. Did you `set(CMAKE_RC_FLAGS "/l 0x809")` in your root `CMakeLists.txt` after your project command? Which CMake version, which generator and which Visual Studion version? What exactly does "not work" means? The option should show up under "Project Configuration Properties/Resources/Command Line/Additional Options".

Comment: @simon-p-r Thanks for the details. I've given you code a try and it seems to work without any problems. See my updated answer for more information.